# Why is the periodate anion not found?

Tags: ions

> Chlorine can be found as the following oxoanions $\ce{ClO–} , \ce{ClO2-}, \ce{ClO3-}, \ce{ClO4-}$ in many chemical stockrooms. However, iodine is never found as $\ce{IO4-}$. Explain this observation.

I didn't really find any reason as to why periodate cannot exist, unlike anions such as flourate where it is limited by flourine's small size. After researching this further, I found that the periodate anion actually exists in compounds such as sodium periodate. Even though it has another form $\ce{IO6^{5-}},$ the periodate anion actually dominates its equilibrium. Thus, I was wondering what the intended/likely answer was?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_periodate

Comment: Bigger atoms tend to have higher coordination numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, $\ce{IO4-}$ does exist and it is called [metaperiodate anion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodate) It can combine with a number of counter ions to form periodates, which may also be regarded as the salts of periodic acid.

> Metaperiodates are typically prepared by the dehydration of sodium
>   hydrogen periodate with nitric acid.
>
> $$\ce{Na3H2IO6 + 2 HNO3 → NaIO4 + 2 NaNO3 + 2 H2O}$$
>
> They can also be generated directly from iodates by treatment with
>   other strong oxidizing agents such as hypochlorites:
>
> $$\ce{NaIO3 + NaOCl → NaIO4 + NaCl}$$
>
> [image]
>
> Metaperiodates adopt a distorted tetrahedral geometry with an average
>   $\ce{I–O}$ distance of 1.78 Å
>
> The ortho- and metaperiodate forms exist in equilibrium.
>
> $\ce{H4IO6− ⇌ IO4- + 2H2O,      K = 29}$
>
> For this reason orthoperiodate is sometimes referred to as the
>   dihydrate of metaperiodate, written $\ce{IO4^-·2H2O}$

One example of salt having metaperiodate ion is [sodium periodate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_periodate)(@Gert). Its preparation is mentioned above. In fact, all other alkali metals and alkaline earth metals forms metaperiodate salts. Some examples include [potassium periodate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_periodate), [rubidium periodate](http://rubidium.atomistry.com/rubidium_periodate.html), [calcium periodate](http://calcium.atomistry.com/calcium_periodate.html) etc.